# How to sort a column through date using OpenXml in c#?

Tags: c#

hey I am using OpenXml library for excel file reading and I have a problem relative to sort a column. **I want to sort my date column in my excel file**.

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
               
                //create a new worksheet.
                Sheet sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild<Sheet>();
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet worksheet = (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;
                IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row> rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>();
                // i have to sort my date column here
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want store in data Table after sorting the rows according to date oldest to newest.